# Сравнение двух таблиц MySQL

Tags: mysql

Как сделать тоже самое на примере MySQL? Как я понимаю, MySQL не поддерживает **FULL OUTER JOIN**.

```
SELECT table1.id, table2.id FROM table1  
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id  
WHERE table1.id IS NULL OR table2.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: вопрос: а зачем?

Comment: хотелось бы добавить все уникальные данные в одну таблицу, а от второй избавиться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FULL OUTER JOIN` в большинстве случаев можно заменить `UNION` с расстановкой данных в нужные колонки и группировкой по общему полю. В вашем случае это будет выглядеть так:

```
select max(id1),max(id2)
  from (
        select id,id as id1,NULL as id2 from table1
        union all
        select id,NULL,id from table2
       ) A
 group by id
having max(id1) is null or max(id2) is null
```

Но если вы хотите получить все уникальные данные для вставки в другую таблицу, то не понятно, зачем вам нужна выборка в две отдельные колонки, запрос получения уникальных данных в одну колонку был бы проще...

Для случая, что в исходных таблицах id уникальны, это выглядело бы так:

```
select id
  from (
        select id from table1
        union all
        select id from table2
       )
  group by id
 having count(1)=1
```

Comment: Спасибо. Согласен, в одну колонку результат выводить логичнее.

Comment: @Денис тогда привел вариант для выборки одной колонки уникальных ...

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Mysql умеет выполнять любой join только через `nested loops`. Поэтому `full outer join` в самом mysql отсутствует вообще, через `nested loops` `full outer join` не выполнить.

`full outer join` от `left join` отличается добавлением строк, которые есть только в правой таблице. Ну вот эти строки можно добавить через union вторым запросом. Поэтому для вашего запроса эквивалент можно собрать так:

```
SELECT table1.id, table2.id FROM table1  
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id  
WHERE table2.id IS NULL
union all
SELECT table1.id, table2.id FROM table2  
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.id = table2.id  
WHERE table1.id IS NULL;
```