# Объединение таблиц с помощью union

Tags: mysql, sql

Как объединить таблицы, что бы выводило категорию и разделы в ней?

У меня только получилось, что выводит номер категории и разделы в ней, а как вывести имя категории?

```
SELECT id, name FROM category UNION SELECT category_id, name FROM sub_category

INSERT INTO `category` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Программы'),
(2, 'Фильмы');

INSERT INTO `sub_category` (`id`, `name`, `category_id`) VALUES
(1, 'Антивирусы', 1),
(2, 'Запись', 1),
(3, 'Интернет', 1),
(4, 'Аудио', 1),
(5, 'Боевики', 2),
(6, 'Фантастика', 2),
(7, 'Ужастики', 2);
```

Comment: думаю вам нужен join, а не union. И вы не сказали как именно выводить. приведите пример ожидаемого вывода на основании приведенных данных. Только имейте ввиду, что любая выборка в SQL строго прямоугольная. количество колонок во всех строках одинаково

Comment: Программы Антивирусы

Comment: Ну если первая строка "программы"-"антивирусы", вторая "программы"-"Запись" и т.п. то как я и сказал выше, вам нужен обычный join

Comment: в каких случаях используют union?

Comment: В таких, как вы привели выше, когда вам надо отдельными строками получить данные из одной таблицы и отдельными, не зависящими от первых, строками данные из другой таблицы

Comment: то есть просто одним запросом вывести больше одной таблицы?

Comment: ну можно и так сказать, если вы результат union сразу выдаете. А так он используется для самых разных преобразований, в которых несколько таблиц надо рассматривать как будто это одна таблица из строк с одной структурой. Например, часто используется для замены full outer join https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/650000/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86-mysql/650025#650025

Answer (score 1):

Возможно имелось в виду использование JOIN, то тогда

```
SELECT cat.name AS категория, s_cat.name as раздел FROM category cat
JOIN sub_category s_cat 
ON s_cat.category_id = cat.id
```

Или возможно вывод в одну строку:

```
SELECT cat.name AS категория, 
((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(s_cat.name SEPARATOR ' / ') AS разделы 
    FROM category cat_i
    JOIN sub_category s_cat 
        ON cat_i.id = s_cat.category_id
    WHERE cat_i.id = cat.id)) FROM category cat
```