# Сравнение двух таблиц Mysql и вывод несоответствия

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Подскажите пожалуйста каким запросом (если такое вообще возможно) можно сравнить таблицы sirovyna и invent все поля у них идентичные и не совпадающие строки вывести в другую таблицу inventold.[image: Таблица sirovyna]

[image: Таблица invent]

Comment: Не совпадающие по какому критерию ? Если запись будет почти такая, только дата будет отличаться на 1 секунду - их то же выводить и что именно выводить оба варианта строки (ведь точно такой парной нет ни в одной из таблиц)

Comment: А вообще что нибудь в этом роде. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/650000/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86-mysql/650025#650025  Запрос можно упростить, если не требуется точно знать в какой из таблиц нашлась уникальная строка и так же сделать группировку по тем колонкам, по которым нужно сравнение

Answer (score 1):

Как на счёт оператора MINUS, можно из большей таблицы просто вычесть меньшую и получить все строки которых нет в меньшей.

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM table_name1
MINUS 
SELECT col1, col2
FROM table_name2;
```

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-minus

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM sirovyna AS s
  LEFT JOIN invent AS i ON s.id = i.id
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM sirovyna AS s
  RIGHT JOIN invent AS i ON s.id = i.id
)
WHERE s.id IS NULL OR i.id IS NULL
```

здесь есть полезная информация на эту тему 
[sql joins as venn diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997365/sql-joins-as-venn-diagram)

[How to do a FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql)