# Сравнить две таблицы бд mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

В одно таблице есть два поле (pole1 и pole2) нужно два этих поля сравнить с другой таблицей имеющей (pole). Подскажите как выполнить запрос sql?

Answer (score 0):

Данный вопрос уже задавался [Сравнение двух таблиц MySQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/650000/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86-mysql). Немного информации о JOIN's https://anton-pribora.ru/articles/mysql/mysql-join/

Answer (score 0):

Где-то так:

```
 SELECT * FROM TableOne t1
 LEFT JOIN TableTwo t2 on t1.id = t2.id
 WHERE t1.pole1 = t2.pole AND t1.pole2 = t2.pole;
```

Comment: Не работает ваш вариант, вот как у меня изначально было SELECT * FROM base WHERE man = '".$people."''

Comment: Мне нужно еще man2 сравнить с $people

Comment: @keaks88, опишите структуры базы

Comment: man и man2 находятся в таблице у них идет id а people находится в другой таблице, при сравнении если у всех 3 совпадают id то выводим определенную запись

Comment: @keaks88, я так понимаю man и man2 находятся в одной таблице и у них один id?

Comment: нет, id могут у них отличаться

Comment: Как, если они в одной строке

Comment: Уточняю, таблица, в таблице поля. У них поля разные

Answer (score 0):

если вязать по pole

```
SELECT t1.pole1, t1.pole2, t2.pole,t3.pole FROM TableOne t1
 LEFT JOIN TableTwo t2 on t1.pole1 = t2.pole
 LEFT JOIN TableTwo t3 on t1.pole2 = t3.pole
```