# MySQL запрос на обьединение

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть две таблицы в одной собрано количество лайков по фотографии, а во второй по той же фото кол-во комментариев. Ну по разным фоткам конечно.

Как обьединить две таблицы в одну, что бы выводились все `photo_id` даже если по нему нет лайка или комментария?

Я делаю так:

```
SELECT
  v_photo_like_count.photo_id,
  v_photo_like_count.like_count,
  v_photo_comment_count.comment_count
FROM v_photo_comment_count
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN v_photo_like_count
    ON v_photo_comment_count.photo_id = v_photo_like_count.photo_id
```

Но в исходной таблице присутствует только одна фотка у которой есть и лайки и комментарии, как сделать что бы `photo_id` выводился в любом случае?

Comment: как то так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/650025/194569 только, конечно без всяких having

Comment: вот еще статейка, которую еще динозавры застали, но ваш случай охватывает http://www.k-press.ru/cs/2009/3/join/join.asp

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае необходим `full join`, которого нет в MySQL, но его можно легко заменить union двух выборок с группировкой по колонке, по которой предполагалось соединение:

```
select photo_id, sum(like_count) like_count, sum(comment_count) comment_count
  from (
    SELECT photo_id, like_count, null comment_count
      from v_photo_like_count
   union all
    SELECT photo_id, null, comment_count
      from v_photo_comment_count
  ) x
group by photo_id
```

Comment: @Rufex Я не понял, что вы хотели этим сказать. Что значит "не реагирует" и как бы оно должно было бы реагировать

Answer (score 1):

Берем таблицу фотографий (она у вас должна быть) и через LEFT JOIN присоединяем сначала таблицу лайков, а потом коментов (или наоборот порядок не важен. Присоединять нужно к исходной таблице)

```
SELECT p.id, l.like_count, c.comment_count
FROM v_photos p
LEFT JOIN v_photo_comment_count c ON c.photo_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN v_photo_like_count l ON l.photo_id = p.id
```

Работать должно быстрее чем через `UNION`

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. `full join` в [MySQL не предусмотрен](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=1604), т.к. без него можно обойтись заменой на `left join ... union ... right join`, что, собственно, тут и надо сделать:

```
select cc.photo_id,
    cc.comment_count,
    ifnull(lc.like_count, 0) as like_count
from v_photo_comment_count cc 
    left join v_photo_like_count lc on cc.photo_id = lc.photo_id

UNION

select lc.photo_id,
    ifnull(cc.comment_count, 0) as comment_count,
    lc.like_count
from v_photo_comment_count cc 
    right join v_photo_like_count lc on cc.photo_id = lc.photo_id
```

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT JOIN` на обе таблицы:

```
select photo.*, t1.num, t2.num
from photo
left join t1 using(f)
left join t2 using(f)
```