# Как объединить и сложить статистику просмотров по дням из двух таблиц?

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужно объединить статистику из двух таблиц с группировкой по дням (day). p1, p2 - разделы сайта, здесь только для наглядности.

tbl_1:

```
p1 | day | p1_views | p1_clicks
-------------------------------
1  | 15  | 100      | 12
-------------------------------
1  | 16  | 98       | 8
-------------------------------
2  | 16  | 74       | 15
-------------------------------
2  | 17  | 50       | 5
```

tbl_2:

```
p2 | day | p2_views | p2_clicks
-------------------------------
7  | 14  | 50       | 1
-------------------------------
7  | 15  | 77       | 13
-------------------------------
8  | 15  | 10       | 0
-------------------------------
7  | 16  | 30       | 2
```

p1,p2 не важны, сгруппировать нужно по дням чтобы в выдаче было так:

```
day | p1_views | p1_clicks | p2_views | p2_clicks
-------------------------------------------------
14  | 0        | 0         | 50       | 1
-------------------------------------------------
15  | 100      | 12        | 87       | 13
-------------------------------------------------
16  | 172      | 23        | 30       | 2
-------------------------------------------------
17  | 50       | 5         | 0        | 0
```

Делаю так, со статистикой выходит беда, считается неверно всё, как только ни колдовал:

```
SELECT sum(tbl_1.p1_views) AS `p1_views`, sum(tbl_1.p1_clicks) AS `p1_clicks`, 
sum(tbl_2.p2_views) AS `p2_views`, sum(tbl_2.p2_clicks) AS `p2_clicks` 
FROM `tbl_1` LEFT JOIN tbl_2 ON tbl_1.day = tbl_2.day GROUP BY day
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/877338/194569

Comment: Можно получить определения таблиц? Чтобы самим не сочинять.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT day FROM tbl_1
              UNION 
              SELECT day FROM tbl_2 )
SELECT cte.day, 
       COALESCE(SUM(tbl_1.p1_views), 0)  p1_views, 
       COALESCE(SUM(tbl_1.p1_clicks), 0) p1_clicks, 
       COALESCE(SUM(tbl_2.p2_views), 0)  p2_views, 
       COALESCE(SUM(tbl_2.p2_clicks), 0) p2_clicks
FROM cte 
LEFT JOIN tbl_1 ON cte.day = tbl_1.day
LEFT JOIN tbl_2 ON cte.day = tbl_2.day
GROUP BY cte.day
```

Для MySQL 5 версии - переместить CTE в подзапрос.